# Parametric numerical integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I would like to solve the integral:
$$ \iiint\frac{e^{-\sqrt{x^2 + k^2}}x^2 \sin{\theta}}{\sqrt{x^2 + k^2}}  dx d\theta d\phi$$
defined in $x \in [0,+\infty]$, $\theta \in [0,\pi]$, $\phi \in [0,2 \pi]$, with the parameter $k > 0$

I have tried to compute a parametric solution in *Mathematica* (v. 10.3) in this way:

```
N[Integrate[Exp[-Sqrt[p^2 + k^2]]*p^2*Sin[θ]/Sqrt[p^2 + k^2],
  {p, 0, ∞}, {θ, 0, π}, Assumptions -> k > 0]]
```

It gives me the error:

> "The integrand has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region"

I have found many different questions with similar problems but I was not able to find a solution. Is there any way I can get a result which will be parametric on $k$?

Comment: `f[k_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[(2 E^-Sqrt[k^2 + p^2] p^2)/Sqrt[k^2 + p^2], {p, 0, Infinity}]; f[1]`

Comment: As far as I know, by calling `N[expression]`, you are asking for the numerical value, which in this case cannot be evaluated, as long as expression depends on k

Comment: The $\theta$ and $\phi$ integrations can be done directly and simply, leaving just the $x$ integration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, as [David G. Stork](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9735/david-g-stork) has also observed, the triple integral simplifies to a single integral:

```
Integrate[Exp[-Sqrt[p^2 + k^2]]*p^2*Sin[θ]/Sqrt[p^2 + k^2],
 {p, 0, Infinity}, {θ, 0, π}, Assumptions -> k > 0]
(*
  Integrate[(2 E^-Sqrt[k^2 + p^2] p^2)/Sqrt[k^2 + p^2], {p, 0, ∞}, Assumptions -> k > 0]
*)
```

Then changing variables `r^2 == p^2 + k^2`, *Mathematica* can finish the integral:

```
Integrate[2 E^-r Sqrt@(r^2 - k^2), {r, k, ∞}, Assumptions -> k > 0]
(*  2 k BesselK[1, k]  *)
```

Here we can check numerically that no mistake has (probably) been made (just noticed that `foo` is [march's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/29734/march) solution):

```
ClearAll[foo];
SetAttributes[foo, Listable];
foo[k_?NumericQ] :=  NIntegrate[(2 E^-Sqrt[k^2 + p^2] p^2)/Sqrt[k^2 + p^2], {p, 0, ∞}]

k0 = RandomReal[4, 5];
foo[k0]
2 k BesselK[1, k] /. k -> k0
(*
  {0.36337, 0.457313, 0.506084, 0.650339, 0.136193}
  {0.36337, 0.457313, 0.506084, 0.650339, 0.136193}
*)
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I see a substitution of variables is somehow helping mathematica reaching the solution. But can you explain why if I use another substitution, for example r = p/k, which leads to Integrate[k E^-kr Sqrt@(r^2 - 1), {r, 1, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> k > 0] does not work?

Comment: @user1584773 (1) In which integral did you substitute, b/c if `p` runs from 0 to infinity, I don't see how `r` can start at 1? (2) What do you mean it does not work: does not evaluate or gives a (seemingly) wrong answer? Note `E^-kr` is not the same as `E^(-k*r)`.